# "Dare" with and without "to"

Tags: verbs, negation, modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs, semi-modals

To my surprise, there's a missing question about this particularly interesting verb, *dare.* All I know about it is the fact it can be in two forms, as an auxiliary (without *to*: "I dare not mention their names") and main (with *to*: "Did anyone dare to admit it?") verb and the difference has something to do with agreeing with subject. Can somebody explain in a greater detail?

Comment: 'Did anyone dare admit it?' is also possible.

Comment: Oops. Had submitted an answer to this when half asleep that was completely wrong, as pointed out by @Matt. Duly deleted. And apologies for any confusion caused by my nonfunctioning brain.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/606455/2085).

Comment: Could be seen `dare` like `need`?
Only in negative or interrogative the use of`dare` without `to` and auxiliary means it doesn`t happen,it is a subjunctive.The another wise it is a common conjugate.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Dare is a semi-modal verb. The speaker can choose whether to use the auxiliary "to" when forming negative and interrogative sentences. For example, "I don't dare (to) go" and "I dare not go" are both correct. Similarly "Dare you go?" and "Do you dare (to) go?" are both correct.

Taken from the [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dare).

Note that when *dare* means *challenge*, it requires *to*, as in:

> I challenge you to ask her out.
>
> I dare you to ask her out.

Comment: Yes, I think, that's a better example of the contrast between the semi-modal and lexical uses.

Comment: Uh… what would be wrong with 'I dare you: ask her out', please?

Comment: To Robbie's comment: that's an entirely different structure with the colon, so nothing's wrong with that either, of course.