# "Dare" (modal) and "dare to"

Tags: grammar, british-english, idiom-meaning, semi-modals

Is there any difference between "I'd dare to say" and "I dare say"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Dare" with and without "to"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43315/dare-with-and-without-to)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - This wasn't covered in the other question and answer.  A shame the OP didn't share his research.

Answer (score 2):

"I dare say" means "probably" or "I expect/imagine/suppose". 
It doesn't mean "I dare to say".
(from "Practical English Usage", M. Swan)

I'd rather use "venture that" to express boldness in saying something.
Hope it helps.
A.

Comment: I see. What I meant it was if "I dare say"   and "I dare to say" have the same meaning. Anyway, thanks

Comment: @Francis Antonia is telling you that they don't have the same meaning.

Comment: I understood it! I merely wanted to outline what I was wondering.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/606455/2085).